# Script failed: when trying to click on button present on second form

Tags: javascript, java, android-emulator, testng, appium

I have written script in javascript for two forms present in an web application and running suite using emulator for mobile device samsung s8 android 9.0
script for first form is working fine that is "Contact Us" button is clickable and start running the script for second form now, the issue with the click on same "Contact Us" button on second form.

CODE for first form:

```
Thread.sleep(2000); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'globalcontent\']/div[3]/div[1]/section/div/form/div[13]/button")).click();
```

CODE for second form:

```
Thread.sleep(2000);
logger1.info("Contact Us button is clicked");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'globalcontent\']/div/div[2]/section/div/form/div[13]/button")).click();
```

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Could you provide a snippet of the HTML layout of the form you're trying to automate? That would help us further debug the issues with your XPath.

Comment: no error messages?
Could it be that the for your second script, the "contact us" button is only visible after changing the resolution?

Comment: Not sure why you're using `\'` since a single quote does not need to be escaped.  Aside from that, though, anytime you have a problem like this, you should break it down into individual steps - check for the existence of the webelement first and/or use an explicit wait (not sleep), assign it to a web element, then click.  Your xpath looks rather fragile.  Show some HTML code in your original post and perhaps a better xpath can be suggested.

Comment: @PixelPlex Yes, 'Contact Us' button is enabled when changing the resolution.